# Why babel transpiles import and export in this case?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-modules

I have this `babel.config.js`:

```js
const presets = [
  [
    "@babel/env",
    {
      targets: {
        edge: "17",
        firefox: "60",
        chrome: "67",
        safari: "11.1",
      },
      useBuiltIns: "usage",
    },
  ],
  ["@babel/preset-react"],
];
```

Why does it transpile es6 `import`/`export` into the following, if all of the above targets support `import`/`export`:

```js
var _styles = require("@material-ui/styles");

var _core = require("@material-ui/core");

exports.default = _default;
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you need to tell Babel explicitly to target ES modules. It doesn't have the ability to infer that from your target browser list.

Looking at the[@babel-env documention](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#targetsesmodules), this is how you would targets supporting esmodules.

```
"@babel/env",
  {
    "targets": {
      "esmodules": true
    }
  }
```

> Please note: when specifying the esmodules target, browsers targets will be ignored.

Comment: Adding `targets: {esmodules: true}` still gives transpilation of `import`/`export`. But I tried `modules: false` as in https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#modules, giving me the correct result.

Comment: Also the individual browser targets will not be ignored with `targets.esmodules=true`, I think. Just the property `targets.browsers` will be ignored.